# Can I ask for programming language resource recommendations here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I wish to ask what are the good resources to understand Python source code written in C language. Like there a book for Ruby i.e. Ruby under a microscope. It deals with low level implementation of Ruby.

I wish to ask same resource for Python. Can I ask this kind of programming language related questions here?

If not what community would fit well for these questions? (Surely not Stack  Overflow)

Comment: Get creative. Ask "What software tools are good for rendering quality programming textbook PDFs?". To prove the correctness of an answer, they'll have to provide links to the PDFs which they claim render well. Check and mate. Along these lines you can also ask "What software tools are good at displaying pictures of delicious seafood restaurants in my area?" for restaurant recommendations, and... well, you get the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wish to ask what are the good resources to understand Python source code written in C language. Like there a book

No. This site provides *software* recommendations, and only those recommendations. We recommend software tools to solve specific problems, not books or sources of information about software tools. From [/help/on-topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), emph. mine:

> This site is for questions asking for **recommendations of software ready-to-use to accomplish a particular task**, that is, “what software can I use to do …?”. While this includes software libraries for development use, note that recommendations of tutorials, data sources, media libraries (e.g. icon collections) etc. are off-topic

There is currently no site on the Stack Exchange network that I know of would accept this type of question.

Comment: that's bad :( 

There should be some kind of site for this

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan Feel free to search [Area 51](//area51.stackexchange.com) and propose it if it doesn't already exist.